# Modifying a vector reference. What gets invalidated?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-corruption

Assume I have the following code:

```
void appendRandomNumbers(vector<double> &result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        result.push_back(rand());
    }
}

vector<double> randomlist;
appendRandomNumbers(randomlist);
for (double i : randomlist) cout << i << endl;
```

The repeated push_back() operations will eventually cause a reallocation and I suspect a memory corruption.
Indeed, the [vector.push_back() documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) says that

> If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references related to the container are invalidated.

After the reallocation happens, which of the scopes will have a correct vector? Will the reference used by appendRandomNumbers be invalid so it pushes numbers into places it shouldn't, or will the "correct" location be known by appendRandomNumbers only and the vector is deleted as soon as it gets out of scope?

Will the printing loop iterate over an actual vector or over a stale area of memory where the vector formerly resided?

**Edit:** Most answers right now say that the vector reference itself should be fine. I have a piece of code similar to the one above which caused memory corruption when I modified a vector received by reference and stopped having memory corruption when I changed the approach. Still, I cannot exclude that I incidentally fixed the real reason during the change. Will experiment on this.

Comment: iterators/pointers and references pointing to the data *in* the container are invalidated. The container itself isn't moving around. If the reference to the container itself got invalidated, it would be pretty much worthless.

Comment: Regarding your **Edit**: That piece of code is wrong then, or you misinterpreted the result. The answers given are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused on what is going on.  `push_back()` can invalidate iterators and references that point to objects in the vector, not the vector itself.  In you situation there will be no invalidation and your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The reference `vector<double> &result` will be fine, the problem would be if you had something referencing the *underlying memory* such as

```
double& some_value = result[74];
result.push_back();   // assume this caused a reallocation
```

Now `some_value` is referencing bad memory, the same would occur with accessing the underlying array using [`data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)

```
double* values = result.data();
result.push_back();  // again assume caused reallocation
```

Now `values` is pointing at garbage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about what gets invalidated. Everything in your example is perfectly behaving code. The issue is when you keep references to data that the vector itself owns. For instance:

```
vector<double> v;
v.push_back(x);
double& first = v[0];
v.push_back(y);
v.push_back(z);
v.push_back(w);
cout << first;
```

Here, `first` is a reference to `v`'s internal data - which *could* get invalidated by one of the `push_back()`s and unless you specifically accounted for the additional size, you should assume that it *was* invalidated so the `cout` is undefined behavior because `first` is a dangling reference. That's the sort of thing you should be worried about - not situations where you pass the whole `vector` itself by reference.